# Keeping a process open and communicating with it in Python

Tags: python

I am doing some iterations using python script. What I do is something like this.

python exec.py variables.in.1 output.out.1

Here 1 is the iteration number.

Now what this does is, it calls an executable using the values in the variables file and then the output of the executable is put into the output file. Unfortunately what I see is that it takes more time by calling the executable again and again.

In stead what I want to do is start the executable once and then send the variables to the executable using the same syntax, i.e. python exec.py variables.in.1 output.out.1.

I need to preserve this syntax is because the variables file is generated externally. I have no control over it, but once it is generated I need to use the executable to create the output file which will then need to be parsed in the required format.

EDIT: I'll try to represent what I am doing in a simplified manner, since its a large code.

```
import sys
import os
import parseinput
import parseoutput

s1=sys.argv[1];s2=sys.argv[2]

op=open(s1,'r');inp=op.readlines();op.close()
variableswrite=parseinput.parseinput(inp)
op=open('pass.dat','w');op.write(variableswrite);op.close()

os.sytem('execute < pass.dat')

op=open('executeout.dat','r');out=op.readlines();op.close()
outwrite=parseoutput.parseoutput(out)
op=open(s2,'w');op.write(outwrite);op.close()
```

This is a very crude way of showing what I am doing. If this is the code exec.py, every time I run it using python exec.py variables.in.1 results.out.1, I'll get an output file using the executable which will be parsed to get the output file.

Instead, if I could keep the 'execute' executable open, and still do python exec.py variables.in.1 results.out.1 where the script would parse the input file and then send it to the open executable which would then create the output, my job would be much faster and efficient.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far and any errors you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way for you to augment `exec.py` to take any number of input/output filename pairs?

If so, the invocation will look like so:

```
python exec.py variables.in.1 output.out.1 ... variables.in.N output.out.N
```

Now, suppose you have 1000 such pairs. You can partition this range into 20 groups of 50 pairs  (for instance). And invoke the script 20 times (concurrently) with different groups:

```
python exec.py variables.in.1 output.out.1 ... variables.in.50 output.out.50
python exec.py variables.in.51 output.out.51 ... variables.in.100 output.out.100
...
python exec.py variables.in.951 output.out.951 ... variables.in.1000 output.out.1000
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that. The input files are given to me only one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

1) Create a daemon process which is running all the time

2) Give list of monitored files or folder as argument

3) Use inotify to detect new incoming files

http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/

4) Every time inotify gives a signal, trigger the transformation inside your daemon procses by calling the method

You cannot keep the syntax same if the syntax has "python" command as naturally this will restart interpreter every time.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for me. What I am doing is using the open source optimization tool DAKOTA. I have my analysis tool that is the executable. Now to do the optimization, DAKOTA will generate the parameters file and want the results file back.

As syntax it needs to call an executable which it'll call as a process, probably as an os.system type of call.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is in the "subprocess" module, which makes it simple to start processes and connect their input and output pipes

To avoid blocking just do the input and output in separate processes. You can do that with "os.fork":

```
import os
import subprocess
execute = subprocess.Popen(
    'execute',
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
if os.fork():
    #feed data into the input
    while True:
        input = ...
        execute.stdin.write(input)
else:
    outGenerator=Out
    #do something with the output
    for outline in execute.stdout:
        print outline
```

Or you can split the input and output code into two files, then use something like this as the "**main**":

```
import os
import subprocess
generateInput = subprocess.Popen(
    ['python','generateInput.py'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
execute = subprocess.Popen(
    'execute',
    stdin=generateInput.stdout,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
generateOutput = subprocess.Popen(
    ['python','generateOutput.py'],
    stdin=execute.stdout
)
execute.communicate()
```

which is just the long way of saying

```
python generateInput.py | execute | python gnerateOutput.py
```